# How to return breeze entities from a specific web api call?

Tags: breeze

I have all my normal breeze queries and updates working pretty perfectly and it is so awesomely slick now that I've gotten used to it!

I of course want to be difficult though, and use breeze to load entities that aren't actually the result of a query.  Or at least not directly.

Basically I have another object that does some logicy stuff using my entity classes to find certain matching objects.  That logic doesn't matter.  The result is that calling the method on that object will return me an `IEnumerable<MyObject>` (actually an `IList<MyObject>`) that I then want to return to breeze to use on the client side.  So I guess it's a query, just that something else is doing the query logic, not breeze passing it's where and orderby clauses.

However at the moment, I just get the error from breeze `Object #<Object> has no method 'getProperty'`

Just to explain how I've tried implementing this:

First Attempt:

```
[HttpGet]
public object SchemasForStatementFile(int fileId)
{
    StatementFile statementFile = _contextProvider.Context.Statements.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == fileId);
    IEnumerable<StatementFileSchema> schemasForFile = _parsingEngine.FindSchemasForFile(statementFile);
    return new { schemas = schemasForFile.ToArray() };
}
```

Second Attempt:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<StatementFileSchema> SchemasForStatementFile(int fileId)
{
    StatementFile statementFile = _contextProvider.Context.Statements.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == fileId);
    IEnumerable<StatementFileSchema> schemasForFile = _parsingEngine.FindSchemasForFile(statementFile);
    return schemasForFile.AsQueryable();
}
```

I get the same error with either approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!

This is exactly the use case for the *JsonResultsAdapter*.  Take a look at the Edmunds sample or the 'default' JsonResultsAdapter in the source.  The idea is that the JsonResultsAdapter will take the results of a query and stipulate the 'entityTypes' that it contains.  It can also morph the data if needed.  For more info, see here:  [General discussion of the JsonResultsAdapter](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-service-data-mapping) and here[JsonResultsAdapter api](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/JsonResultsAdapter.html#method_%3Cctor%3E%20JsonResultsAdapter).

Comment: Ok thanks for the clarification.  I had read through the JsonResultsAdapter page, but I had interpreted it as something required for more abstract results.  What I mean is that I am returning, from the server-side, the same entities that breeze would normally return, just filtered and organised as I want :)  Not that I am complaining all the awesome work you guys have done, but I kinda expected breeze to just know how to read these results.  It's the uncanny valley effect - The closer breeze gets to being perfect, the more strange it is when I actually have to do some work!! ;)

Comment: Actually, as long as you are using the default Json.net serializer with its default settings then one of the attributes on every entity will be '$type'.  As long as this matches one of the types that Breeze already knows about then Breeze will convert the data into a 'real' entity.

Comment: That's what I was expecting, and it turns out there's a simple reason why my entities weren't being automagically mapped -they weren't the real entities being returned, but the EF proxy objects.  So as is usual with my questions, your answer clarifies the breeze behaviour, and points out where my dumbass code has made your magic framework struggle :)